# Errors in align environment

Tags: errors, align

The following block of code comes up with 10 errors.

```
\begin{align}
\|\tau(\textbf{x})-\tau(\textbf{y})\| &= \|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\| \\
\|\tau(\textbf{x})-\tau(\textbf{y})\|^2 &= \|\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\|^2 \\ 
(\tau(\textbf{x})-\tau(\textbf{y})) \cdot (\tau(\textbf{x})-     \tau(\textbf{y})) &= (\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}\) \cdot (\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}) \\
\|\tau(\textbf{x})\|^2 - 2(\tau(\textbf{x}) \cdot \tau(\textbf{y})) +     \|\tau(\textbf{y})\|^2 &= \|\textbf{x}\|^2 - 2(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y}) + \|\textbf{y}\|^2 \\
-2(\tau(\textbf{x}) \cdot \tau(\textbf{y})) &= -2(\textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y}) \\
\tau(\textbf{x}) \cdot \tau(\textbf{y}) &= \textbf{x} \cdot \textbf{y}   \text{ , proving the Lemmma.} \\
\end{align}
```

The errors are:

```
! Missing } inserted, 
! Missing $ inserted, 
! Missing { inserted, 
! Missing } inserted, 
! Missing { inserted, 
! Missing $ inserted, 
! Missing \endgroup inserted, 
! undefined control sequence, ! Misplaced \omit, 
! Missing { inserted.
```

Each of the errors are apparently in the line with `\end{align}`. I can't for the life of me see what's wrong with the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got a `\)`in the third line.

Comment: You have `\)` in the third line of the environment, which should be `)`. You also have ``\\`` in the last line, that you should remove. The final comment should go after the display and `gather` is better than `align` in this case.

Comment: Also next time please post a full minimal example instead of a sniplet. You might also want to do something different than `\textbf{x}` and friends. Either use `\mathbf{x}` or load the `bm` package and use `\bm{x}` to get italic bold. `\mathbf` switch to the math upright bold. `\textbf` is the *text* upright bold

Answer (score 2):

Your main error has been mentioned in comments already. I tried to improve your code a bit. The most important suggestion is to use a custom command for your bold symbols. Like this, you can change the appearance for all occurrences with an ease. And the code will look nicer and will be easier to read.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\norm}[1]{\lVert}{\rVert}{#1}
\usepackage{bm}
% define a command with a name more telling than mine in order to have nicer syntax and flexibility afterwards. 
\newcommand*{\wtistb}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} % whatever this is supposed to be

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \norm{\tau(\wtistb{x})-\tau(\wtistb{y})} &= \norm{\wtistb{x}-\wtistb{y}} \\
    \norm{\tau(\wtistb{x})-\tau(\wtistb{y})}^2 &= \norm{\wtistb{x}-\wtistb{y}}^2 \\ 
    \bigl(\tau(\wtistb{x})-\tau(\wtistb{y})\bigr) \cdot \bigl(\tau(\wtistb{x}) - \tau(\wtistb{y})\bigr) &= (\wtistb{x}-\wtistb{y}) \cdot (\wtistb{x}-\wtistb{y}) \\ % fixed \) here
    \norm{\tau(\wtistb{x})}^2 - 2 \bigl(\tau(\wtistb{x}) \cdot \tau(\wtistb{y})\bigr) + \norm{\tau(\wtistb{y})}^2 &= \norm{\wtistb{x}}^2 - 2(\wtistb{x} \cdot \wtistb{y}) + \norm{\wtistb{y}}^2 \\
    -2 \bigl(\tau(\wtistb{x}) \cdot \tau(\wtistb{y})\bigr) &= -2(\wtistb{x} \cdot \wtistb{y}) \\
    \tau(\wtistb{x}) \cdot \tau(\wtistb{y}) &= \wtistb{x} \cdot \wtistb{y} \text{,\qquad proving the Lemmma.} % removed \\ here
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}`? Is there some particular advantage in using the "more powerful" form  `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`?

Comment: @campa this is absolutely the same. See the `mathtools` manual on page 26. No particular reason why I used this.